# Is this question about ethics of uploading photos of people on-topic on Photography?

Tags: discussion

Over at Travel we are not sure about the on-topicness of this question:

[Ethics of uploading photos taken on holidays](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10595/2509)

Would this be on-topic at Photography? If so, are you happy to have it migrated from Travel to Photography?

Answer (score 4):

I think we've had similar asked, so it's probably more on topic over here.